# Select multiple rows with max date

Tags: mysql, sql, maxdate

I'm new to mysql so please help me out with this.

I have a table containing the following columns:

```
nr  |   date   |  hour  |  user  |  shop  |  brand  |  categ  | product | price | promo
183   02/03/14   17:06    cristi    186     brand1    categ 1    prod 1    299     no
184   02/03/14   17:06    cristi    186     brand2    categ 2    prod 2    399     yes
184   01/03/14   17:06    cristi    186     brand3    categ 3    prod 3    199     no
```

The query that I use is

```
SELECT * 
FROM evaluari 
WHERE magazin = %s HAVING MAX(data)
```

Where "s" is the shop ID (186).

but that return only the first row containing 02/03/14 date. How can I show both/all rows containing the same max date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try not to name colums with reserved words like "date" it might cause you problems.
You can do what you want like this:

```
SELECT * FROM evaluari WHERE magazin = 186 AND date = (SELECT MAX(date) from evaluari WHERE magazin = 186)
```

Comment: You want to put the magazin id to max date select or `SELECT MAX(date) from evaluari` could be an awful table scan...

Comment: @Ray: How to "put the magazin id to max date select"?

Comment: `(SELECT MAX(date) from evaluari Where magazin = 186)`

Comment: @SariAlalem also, without the magazin =186  the select, the max date might be tied to a magazin not being looked for, and you'd get zero results.

Comment: You might want to use the modifies answer, as its more optimied as Ray suggested :)

Comment: can I sort the rows by categ? How can I do that?

Comment: add to the end of the query "order by categ asc" or instead of asc, desc

Answer (score 1):

Probably, not optimal, but at first swing, you could do this

```
 SELECT * FROM evaluari 
   where date IN (SELECT date FROM evaluari WHERE magazin = %s HAVING MAX(date)) 
          AND magazin = %s;
```

In fact, this really rubs me as nasty... going to try to figure something smoother.  Stay tuned :)

Comment: The `HAVING` clause seems overkill in this query, why not just `SELECT MAX(date) WHERE magazin = %s` in the inner query?

Comment: @AndréLaszlo yes, that's what I think, going to look for another better solution, but the above would work.